flowable workflow, how to group multi-instance tasks?
To use the flowable workflow, assume that flow A->B->C->B->C->D, where ABCD is UserTask and B is multi-instance UserTask. If the first time I enter multi-instance node B, I create three tasks :t1,t2, and t3, and the second time I enter multi-instance node B, I create two tasks :t4,t5,t6, but 6 HistoricTaskInstances with 6 different Executionids, How do I divide six HistoricTaskInstances into two groups of tasks?
